# Why do I get a Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php

For some reason this isn't working. It works in a class on the same page, but not in this one.

```
class ChatLib {
    private $db;

    function ChatLib($db){
        $this->$db = $db;
    }
}
```

I get `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string`

Comment: This code by itself certainly does not output the error you mention. I assume you have additional code where you try to output something? I suggest you post _that_ code too? And _please_ use the `edit` button below your question to do so. Do _not_ post additional details as a command here...

Comment: Not really, I use `$ChatLib = new ChatLib($db);` to make it, but there error is on line 5 of the post

Comment: @Dinistro I think the class name serves the same purpose in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reference object properties, do not use the `$` prefix. This is your problem:

```
$this->$db = $db;
```

It should be:

```
$this->db = $db;
```

The reason it fails with this error is that by using the `$` prefix, you are converting `$db` to a string, and then trying to access the result of that as a class property.

Example to illustrate:

```
$variable = 'a';
$obj->$variable; // same as doing $obj->a;
```

Here, `$variable` is a string so this works, but if it wasn't a string, it would get converted and produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to the following and it now works. An answer with an explanation is still appreciated, however. Thanks!

```
class ChatLib {
    private $db;

    function ChatLib($dbIn){
        $db = $dbIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Actually I thought this was an answer, until I realized `$db` is local.

Answer (score 0):

For example, 
    $data = 'toto';

If you try do 
        $this->$data = 'something';
you try to do 
        $this->toto = 'something';

Can you try that ?

```
function ChatLib($db){
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->$db` means "the object attribute with the name equals to the content of `$db`". E.g. if `$db` is currently containing "foo", it will mean the same as `$this->foo`. That's the reason, why the variable, presenting an attribut name (in this case `$db`) must be a string. If not, PHP will try to cast it to string. And a convertation of an (`MySQLi`) object to a string doesn't work and causes an error. The correct variant is:

```
class ChatLib {
    private $db;

    function ChatLib($db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```